# Substitution needed to transform the original to 2 equations with 2 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found the following question:-

"Given that $\frac {1}{a} - \frac {1}{b}=\frac {X}{a-b}$ and $\frac {a}{b} + \frac {b}{a}=Y$. Express $Y$ in terms of $X$."

It is not that difficult to do because, somehow,

$-X = \dfrac {a^2 - 2ab + b^2} {ab}$ and hence, $Y = 2 - X$.

However, the question is one of the exercises in the chapter 'solving linear simultaneous equations'.

At the most I can let $p = a/b$ and $q = b/a$. Two equations ($pq = 1$ and $Y = p + q$) are formed.

The same result can still be obtained but is directly from the calculation of X instead of solving some relevant simultaneous equations.

Any other suggestion?